# Polyline not being drawn on map

Tags: javascript, arcgis-js-api

I'm trying to draw/animate my runs on a map.

I have an array of points which makeup the path of my run. I want to iterate over them and add them to the path on the map, one at a time. On each iteration I add the point to the PolyLine and extend the map to fit all the points.

It seems to be extending the line properly, but it is not drawing the line on the map. What am I doing wrong?

```js
var paths = [[[-82.705727,28.068855],[-82.705728,28.068855],[-82.70572,28.068903],[-82.705707,28.068957],[-82.705694,28.069006],[-82.705681,28.069053],[-82.705676,28.069121],[-82.705658,28.069242],[-82.705628,28.06931],[-82.705597,28.069351],[-82.705561,28.069394],[-82.705488,28.06952],[-82.705477,28.069541],[-82.705439,28.069684],[-82.705431,28.06973],[-82.705403,28.069865],[-82.705392,28.069953],[-82.705386,28.069977],[-82.705359,28.070116],[-82.705341,28.070186],[-82.705305,28.070328],[-82.705294,28.070379],[-82.705253,28.070519],[-82.705239,28.070589],[-82.705216,28.070723],[-82.705207,28.070785],[-82.705165,28.070913],[-82.70514,28.070975],[-82.705089,28.071103],[-82.70506,28.071189],[-82.705003,28.07132],[-82.704982,28.071362],[-82.70491,28.071483],[-82.704881,28.071528],[-82.704812,28.071662],[-82.704795,28.07171],[-82.704766,28.071842],[-82.704749,28.071909],[-82.704713,28.072026],[-82.704678,28.072158],[-82.704637,28.072292],[-82.704627,28.072362],[-82.704599,28.072499],[-82.704579,28.072585],[-82.704557,28.072725],[-82.70455,28.072774],[-82.704537,28.072903],[-82.704535,28.072922],[-82.704498,28.073061],[-82.704485,28.073127],[-82.704463,28.07326],[-82.704434,28.073381],[-82.704398,28.073522],[-82.704377,28.073595],[-82.70434,28.073741],[-82.704321,28.073815],[-82.704288,28.073964],[-82.704275,28.074011],[-82.704245,28.074157],[-82.70423,28.074233],[-82.704207,28.074377],[-82.704195,28.074446],[-82.704164,28.074597],[-82.704146,28.074698],[-82.704123,28.07485],[-82.704108,28.074923],[-82.704073,28.075066],[-82.70405,28.075192],[-82.704024,28.07533],[-82.704015,28.075387],[-82.703991,28.07553],[-82.703971,28.075628]]]

require([
  "dojo/_base/Color",
  "esri/map",
  "esri/layers/OpenStreetMapLayer",
  "esri/geometry/Point", 
  "esri/symbols/SimpleMarkerSymbol",
  "esri/geometry/Polyline", 
  "esri/symbols/SimpleLineSymbol",
  "esri/geometry/webMercatorUtils", 
  "esri/graphic", 
  "esri/layers/GraphicsLayer", 
  "esri/SpatialReference",
  "dojo/dom", 
  "dojo/dom-attr", 
  "esri/geometry/Extent",
  "dojo/domReady!"
], function (Color, Map, OpenStreetMapLayer, Point, SimpleMarkerSymbol, Polyline, SimpleLineSymbol, webMercatorUtils, Graphic, GraphicsLayer, SpatialReference, dom, domAttr, Extent) {
  (async ()=>{
    console.log("starting");

    var map_div = document.getElementById('main_map');

    var map, openStreetMapLayer;
    map = new Map(map_div, {
      center: [-82.452606, 27.964157],
      zoom: 12
    });

    openStreetMapLayer = new OpenStreetMapLayer();
    map.addLayer(openStreetMapLayer);

    var spatial_reference = new SpatialReference({wkid: 4326});

    var start = paths[0].shift();
    var start_pos = new Point(start[0], start[1], spatial_reference);

    var polyline_layer = new GraphicsLayer({id: "polyline"});
    var polyLine = new esri.geometry.Polyline(spatial_reference);
    var polyline_symbol = new SimpleLineSymbol();

    polyline_layer.add(new esri.Graphic(polyLine, polyline_symbol));
    map.graphics.add(polyline_layer);

    polyLine.addPath([start_pos]);

    map.on("update-end", function(){
      console.log("updated");
    });


    for(var i=0; i<paths[0].length; i++){
      console.log("extending");

      let point = paths[0][i];
      let pos = new Point(point[0], point[1], spatial_reference);

      polyLine.insertPoint(0, i+1, pos);

      console.log(polyLine.paths);

      map.setExtent(polyLine.getExtent());

      polyline_layer.redraw();

      await new Promise(d=>setTimeout(d, 2500));
    }
  })();


});
```

```css
html,
body,
#main_map {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://js.arcgis.com/3.41/init.js"></script>
<link href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.41/esri/css/esri.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="main_map"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Map.graphics` is a `GraphicsLayer`, in your code you trying to add another one to it instead of a `Graphic`.

You have two options,

1. add the polyline graphic to `Map.graphics`

```
map.graphics.add(new esri.Graphic(polyLine, polyline_symbol));
```

2. add `polyline_layer` to the map layers using `Map.addLayer(..)`

```
map.addLayer(polyline_layer);
```

BTW, if using 1) you do not need the extra `GraphicsLayer`